Error: Method not found: 'dartify'. after adding cloud_firestore to flutter web project
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_web-5.10.1/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:11:23: Error: Method not found: 'dartify'.
return core_interop.dartify(jsObject);
^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_web-5.10.1/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:19:23: Error: Method not found: 'jsify'.
return core_interop.jsify(dartObject, customJsify);
^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_web-5.10.1/lib/src/interop/auth.dart:36:22: Error: Method not found: 'customJSList'.
persistence: customJSList(persistences),
^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
Exited (1).
I am trying to access a cloud_firestore database. What could be going wrong?
I am trying to access the cloud firestore database for a flutter web app.

Update the packages to latest verson, run flutter pub get and try again. If still facing same prblm add the firebase related code in question and we can discuss it further.

Looks like deleting the pubspec.lock and running flutter pub get solve the issue
